# Можно ли в процедуре несколько раз использовать один и тот же запрос?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Пример:

```
for rec in (query1)
   loop
        select * from query1;
   end loop;
```

Чтобы два раза не писать `query1` и не загружать БД повторным выполнением запроса, можно ли сохранить куда-то результаты запроса и в дальнейшем их использовать?

Что-то вроде курсора, но чтобы из него можно было делать выборку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вам подойдут временные таблицы:

```
create global temporary table temp_table_transaction
 on commit delete rows
 as
 select * from dummy where 1=0
```

[ccылка](http://orasource.ru/vremennyie-tablitsyi-v-oracle.html)

Comment: @ХэшКод, ссылка в ответе глючит, исправить не получилось. Оформлено вроде верно.

Comment: Удалил битую. Добавил ссылку на другой ресурс.

Comment: @jmu, это известная проблема с ссылками.  См. [Не работает разметка для некоторых ссылок](http://hashcode.ru/questions/76015/).

Comment: будем знать спасибо. только я предыдущую ссылку сбрасывал без пробелов, но там было много знаков ":".

Answer (score 2):

> можно ли сохранить куда-то результаты запроса и в дальнейшем их использовать?

Да, мoжно. Результат запроса сохранить во вложенную таблицу, затем исползовать её во всех частях последующих SQL запросов как обычную таблицу.

```sql
create or replace type keyrec is object (empid number, depid number)
/
create or replace type keyarr is table of keyrec
/
var rc refcursor
declare
    keys keyarr;
    cur sys_refcursor;
begin
    open cur for
    select keyrec (employee_id, department_id)
    from hr.employees
    where manager_id = 100;
    fetch cur bulk collect into keys;

    open :rc for
    select k.empid, last_name||','||first_name name, department_name 
    from table (keys) k 
    join hr.employees e on e.employee_id=k.empid
    join hr.departments d on d.department_id=k.depid
    where employee_id in (
        select empid from table (keys) k where k.depid in (30,20));
end;
/
```

Блок выше даст такой результат:

```
     EMPID NAME                 DEPARTMENT_NAME               
---------- -------------------- ------------------------------
       114 Raphaely,Den         Purchasing                    
       201 Hartstein,Michael    Marketing
```