# Как передавать динамическую таблицу как параметер во вспомогательные функции?

Tags: sql, функции, oracle, plsql

Существует главная функция, в ней запущен цикл по записям некоторого запроса. Внутри главной функции запускаются вспомогательные функции, которым в качестве параметра передается некая динамическая таблица, которая после того как все функции отработают должна исчезнуть. Но каждая из этих функций может дополнить данную таблицу.

Примерная архитектура: главная функция:

```
> main_function return table2 pipelined
> is 
>      begin
>          for rec in (select id from device)
>          loop
>               ...
>                insert into table1 values(rec.id);
>                ...
>                subfunction1(table1);
>                ...
>                subfunction2(table1);
>                ...
>                subfunction3(table1);
>                ...
>          end loop;
>      end;
```

Пример подфункции:

```
>     subfunction1 return varchar2 is
>         begin
>         ...
>          v:=чему-нибудь равно
>         insert into table1 values(v)
>         end;
```

Структура таблицы table1

```
id
100
202
303
```

Как создать такую таблицу?
Как сделать так, чтобы данная конструкция не грузила БД?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как вариант можно использовать для этого temporary tables. вы создаете временную таблицу в своей БД (которая там существует постоянно так же как как и обычная таблица). данные в такой таблице существуют только в пределах одной сессии (как вариант в пределах одной транзакции). выиграш в перфоманс по сравнению с обычными не очень большой (не помню точно, кажется за счет того что не пишутся данные для отката транзакций), но в то же время можно использовать индексы.

в главной функции вы наполняете временную таблицу данными (напр. список задач которые надо выполнить). после чего вызываете до тех пор пока:

```
1) select count(*) from temporary_table into task_count
```

возвращает результат отличный от нуля, делаете выборку:

```
2) select * from temporary_table where rownum < 2
3) делаем что-то полезное 
4) возвращаемся к шагу 1.
```

google: oracle temporary tables

[похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/76193/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-pl-sql-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81)

Answer (score 3):

Можно создать локальную переменную как копию таблицы в памяти, передавать ссылку на неё в функции, а в конце вставка всех записей этой переменной в таблицу. Вот так:

```sql
<<mainfun>> 
declare
    type tab1row is record (id number, memo varchar2 (16));
    type tab1arr is table of tab1row;
    tab1 tab1arr := tab1arr ();

    procedure subfun1 (tab1 in out nocopy tab1arr) is
    begin
        tab1.extend; tab1(tab1.count) := tab1row (1, 'by subfun1'); 
    end;    
    procedure subfun2 (tab1 in out nocopy tab1arr) is
    begin
        tab1.extend; tab1(tab1.count) := tab1row (2, 'by subfun2'); 
    end;
begin 
    tab1 := tab1arr ();
    subfun1 (tab1);  
    subfun2 (tab1);
    forall ix in 1..tab1.count 
        insert into tab1 values (tab1(ix).id, tab1(ix).memo);
end;
/
```

Результат:

```
select * from tab1;

        ID MEMO            
---------- ----------------
         1 by subfun1      
         2 by subfun2
```